# Simple Torch Application in XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I am trying to build a simple torch application for iOS 5 as described in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AudioVideo/RN-AVFoundation/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010717-CH1-DontLinkElementID_17 but i am getting "Apple Match-O Linker Error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_AVMediaTypeVideo", referenced from:
      -[FirstViewController viewDidLoad] in FirstViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help appreciated

---

Anybody ?

Additionally: it only happens when running the project, no errors if i just clean & Build, and the code completion detects the library.

Thanks

Comment: Remove reference to the framework and add it back in.  You also might get more specific about which header to import.  Also try #import <AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to link your project with the AVFoundation framework first.
If you're already doing that, make sure you're building for armv7 and not just armv6.
Check it in your project settings > Target > Build Settings > Architecture

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the quick reply. The fact is that i am already linking to the AVFoundation framework adding 
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
Also tried changing Targets>Architectures>Architectures to armv6, (it was set to Standard (armv7)) and removed armv7 from valid architectures. None of these worked.

Comment: Try to clean you project with Product - Clean or/and relaunch Xcode. Deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<your_app_name> also  can helps sometimes.

Comment: @CharasOverride it should be pointed out that linking is completely different than importing the header so your code will compile. Linking happens after compilation, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29 .

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

Linker errors like this indicate that a symbol is missing when the app is being linked. Most system symbols like these, come from system frameworks. So, I was missing a framework in my project that contains AVCaptureDevice and AVMediaTypeVideo.

To solve it, i just added the AVFoundation framework following this tutorial: http://www.thinketg.com/Company/Blogs/11-03-20/Xcode_4_Tips_Adding_frameworks_to_your_project.aspx

Now it runs !